# What is the purpose of StrokeForm?

Tags: graphics, undocumented, built-in-symbols, drawing

Symbol `` System`StrokeForm `` is present already in *Mathematica* version 8 (but not in version 5.2).

Currently, it is used in built-in themes, for example:

```
FrameStyle /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", Plot]
```

> ```
> {{StrokeForm[Opacity[0]], StrokeForm[Opacity[0]]}, {Automatic, None}}
> ```

More importantly, when we use the [Drawing Tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html) palette and change the color and/or opacity using the color setter from the "Stroke" section, in the resulting expression corresponding `Hue` and `Opacity` directives are wrapped by `StrokeForm` (but not `Thickness`, `Dashing`, `CapForm` and `JoinForm` which also can be set using the tools from this section). Here is an example of graphics I created using purely the Drawing Tools palette of *Mathematica* 8.0.4:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.000363078054770101], Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}], 
  CapForm["Round"], JoinForm[{"Miter", 4.6000000000000005}], 
  StrokeForm[{Hue[0.31666666666666665, 0.9459459459459459, 1.], Opacity[0.74]}], 
  EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0], Opacity[1]}], EdgeForm[None], 
  Arrow[{{-0.06093314763231206, 0.3726369545032495}, {0.5193825441039923, 
   -0.20767873723305486}}]}, ImagePadding -> {{0., 1.}, {1., 0.}}, 
 ImageSize -> {374., Automatic}, PlotRange -> {{-1.0416666666666667, 
  1.0416666666666667}, {-1.04, 1.04}}, PlotRangePadding -> Automatic]
```

As one can see, it contains `StrokeForm` wrapped around `Hue` and `Opacity` directives.

At the same time, this symbol remains undocumented even in version 13:

[image: screesnhot]

**What is the purpose of this symbol? Are there any benefits to using it?**

Comment: I've never seen this symbol before but just playing around with it you can get an idea what it does.  Compare `Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, FrameStyle -> StrokeForm[Blue], Frame -> True]` with `Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, FrameStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the question myself, I would say that `StrokeForm` is one of specialized compound-type [graphics directives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html): `EdgeForm`, `FaceForm`, `StrokeForm`. They are specialized because each affects rendering only a subset of [graphics objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsObjects.html). And they are compound-type because each can contain other graphics directives.

Specifically `StrokeForm` affects rendering of stroke-like objects: `Line`, `Arrow`, `BSplineCurve`, `BezierCurve`, edges of `Polygon`-like objects, axes and frames of `Graphics`, etc. But it doesn't affect `Point`, `Tube`, etc.

Examples:

```
{Graphics[{StrokeForm[{Red, Thickness[1/2]}], Rectangle[]}],
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[1/2]}], Rectangle[]}]}
```

> [image: output]

```
Graphics3D[{StrokeForm[{Red, Thick}], Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]
```

> [image: output]

```
Graphics3D[{StrokeForm[Dashed], Cuboid[]}]
```

> [image: output]